# C# multiple tcpclients at the same time

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener, tcpserver

I have followed the tcpclient and tcplistener examples on the msdn page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

I am trying to connect to a few pieces of hardware that I have a tcp echo server on. I can create a single tcpclient and connect to one board and send and receive an echo full bore with millisecond delays. I can connect to the second board by itself with millisecond delays. I cannot connect to two boards at the same time and send a string with a response even if i only do this one time and return out of the loop.

I basically took the async client example and added some code to fire it with a button:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AsynchronousClient client1 = new AsynchronousClient();
        AsynchronousClient client2 = new AsynchronousClient();

        client1.Begin("192.168.1.10");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        client2.Begin("192.168.1.11");
    }
```

this code dies. in the end, I want to be able to connect to a few pieces of my hardware and send requests every second or so to query their data that they might have accumulated. I dont think I understand tcp well enough to make this work, but I thought I should be able to talk to two clients asynchronously. I have tried implementing this with threads, tasks, and anything else I can think of, but I cannot reliably talk to two servers at the same time with my app. Any insight would help. Thanks.

Edit:

Here is what I am using now. Is this a safe way to do this? I have not written in any error handling yet. Also, I am a hardware engineer and do not live in the c# world and am trying to learn how to properly use this language.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Swordfish
{
    class SwordfishClient
    {
        private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent receiveSizeDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent receiveMessageDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent parsedDataDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        byte[] Size = new byte[2];
        byte[] Message = new byte[1024];

        public event Action<InPacket> NewPacket;

        public void Connect(string address, int port)
        {
            if (!client.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BeginConnect(address, port, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                    connectDone.WaitOne();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void SendMessage(byte[] data)
        {
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                sendDone.Reset();
                client.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);      
                Trace.WriteLine("Waiting on SendCallback: " + sendDone.WaitOne());

                receiveSizeDone.Reset();
                client.BeginReceive(Size, 0, 2, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveSizeCallback), client);                          
                Trace.WriteLine("Waiting on ReceiveSizeCallback: " + receiveSizeDone.WaitOne());

                receiveMessageDone.Reset();
                client.BeginReceive(Message, 0, BitConverter.ToUInt16(Size, 0), 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMessageCallback), client);               
                Trace.WriteLine("Waiting on ReceiveMessageCallback: " + receiveMessageDone.WaitOne());

                parsedDataDone.Reset();
                parsePacket(Message, BitConverter.ToUInt16(Size, 0));
                parsedDataDone.WaitOne();         
            }
        }

        private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            client.EndConnect(ar);
            connectDone.Set();
        }

        private static void ReceiveSizeCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            Trace.WriteLine("-------------------");
            Trace.WriteLine("Received Header Size: " + bytesRead);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                receiveSizeDone.Set();
            }
        }

        private static void ReceiveMessageCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            Trace.WriteLine("-------------------");
            Trace.WriteLine("Received Message Size: " + bytesRead);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                receiveMessageDone.Set();
            }
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Trace.WriteLine("-------------------");
            Trace.WriteLine("Bytes Sent: " + bytesSent);
            sendDone.Set();
        }

        private void parsePacket(byte[] data, int size)
        {
            Queue<byte> receivedBytes = new Queue<byte>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size - 2; i++)
            {
                receivedBytes.Enqueue(data[i]);
            }

            byte[] statusBytes = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(i => receivedBytes.Dequeue()).ToArray();
            StatusCode status = (StatusCode)Enum.ToObject(typeof(StatusCode), BitConverter.ToUInt16(statusBytes, 0));

            byte[] messageBytes = Enumerable.Range(0, size - 4).Select(i => receivedBytes.Dequeue()).ToArray();

            NewPacket.Invoke(new InPacket(status, messageBytes));


            Trace.WriteLine("-------------------");
            Trace.WriteLine("Size: " + size);
            Trace.WriteLine("-------------------");
            Trace.WriteLine("Status: " + status);
            Trace.WriteLine("-------------------");

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                Trace.Write(data[i] + " ");
                if (i> 0 && i % 75 == 0)
                    Trace.WriteLine("");

                if(i == size - 2)
                    Trace.WriteLine("\r\n----------End of Message: This should all be zero------");
            }
            Trace.WriteLine("\r\n----------------------------------------------------------\r\n");

            for(int i =0; i < Message.Length; i++)
            {
                Message[i] = 0;
            }

            parsedDataDone.Set();
        }
    }
}

Took 7.5514 milliseconds to connect.
-------------------
Bytes Sent: 2
Waiting on SendCallback: True
-------------------
Received Header Size: 2
Waiting on ReceiveSizeCallback: True
-------------------
Received Message Size: 236
Waiting on ReceiveMessageCallback: True
-------------------
Size: 238
-------------------
Status: STATUS_LOG
-------------------
6 0 3 91 69 84 72 69 82 78 69 84 93 32 65 99 99 101 112 116 101 100 32 99 111 110 110 101 99 116 105 111 110 32 102 114 111 109 32 49 48 46 54 52 46 49 46 49 48 58 50 52 53 48 57 32 45 62 32 112 111 114 116 32 53 48 48 48 48 10 23 3 91 69 84 72 
69 82 78 69 84 93 32 65 99 99 101 112 116 101 100 32 99 111 110 110 101 99 116 105 111 110 32 102 114 111 109 32 49 48 46 54 52 46 49 46 49 48 58 50 52 53 49 48 32 45 62 32 112 111 114 116 32 53 48 48 48 49 10 23 3 91 69 84 72 69 82 78 69 84 93 
32 84 114 121 105 110 103 32 116 111 32 99 111 110 110 101 99 116 32 116 111 32 49 48 46 54 52 46 49 46 49 48 58 53 48 48 48 50 10 23 1 91 114 101 99 118 95 99 97 108 108 98 97 99 107 93 32 103 111 116 32 50 32 98 121 116 101 115 32 111 110 32 99 111 110 
102 105 103 32 112 111 114 116 10 23 0 
----------End of Message: This should all be zero------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
----------------------------------------------------------

[ETHERNET] Accepted connection from 10.64.1.10:24509 -> port 50000
[ETHERNET] Accepted connection from 10.64.1.10:24510 -> port 50001
[ETHERNET] Trying to connect to 10.64.1.10:50002
[recv_callback] got 2 bytes on config port
```

Comment: "this code dies" ??? What does that mean? With the code and information given we cannot diagnose the problem. Post complete code and tell us what you want to achieve. Probably, you should use synchronous IO which is easier. MSDN socket examples are not only garbage but also poison because they lead you down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

That code probably dies because when this method ends, those client variables get out of scope and at some point they are reclaimed by the garbage collector. You should show the server code as well to see if there is anything fishy.

Take a look to this example of TCP communication : https://github.com/vtortola/AynchronousTCPListener

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: The server code is the tcp echo server from the xilinx sdk using lwip. I havent modified it at all and seems to be super responsive when I am just making one client in c#. Ill check your code out.